# count all array in pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I need your help to count all array from all my "doc" documents.

sample this i have 4 document with different array list:

```
[{
    "uid": "111",
    "data": [{
        "eid": "111a",
        "ori": ""
    },
    {
        "eid": "111b",
        "ori": ""       
    }]
},
{
    "uid": "222",
    "data": [{
        "eid": "222a",
        "ori": ""
    }]
},
{
    "uid": "333",
    "data": [{
        "eid": "333a",
        "ori": ""
    }]
},
{
    "uid": "444",
    "data": [{
        "eid": "444a",
        "ori": ""
    },
    {
        "eid": "444b",
        "ori": ""       
    }]
}]
```

how i can count total data on all my documents ? in this sample is 6 by ori. Already this:

```
db.doc.find({"data.ori": ""}).count()
```

try many methods from stackoverflow, but not luck.. if you have any idea to do this or have tutorial for this, let me know and thanks.

Comment: Wait, so do you want to count all the arrays being used by a python program? The question is not phrased clearly.

Comment: yes.. i use pymongo, basically i want count ori in that doc.. so if i use .count() in pymongo, value should 6 instead 4

Comment: So you want to count the number of times "ori" appears in the data in the doc?

Comment: yes correct.. already try above methods but result always 4.

Comment: Ok, is it all the arrays in the program, or are the arrays grouped together in a dictionary?

Comment: Sorry.. i'm new in mongodb and pymongo. that list is each document by uid on my mongoDB. so i confuse about what you mean array by program or dic.

Comment: What he means is that the data you posted above isn't a valid python data structure.

Comment: i edit the sample structure, is that correct ? because on mlab they give list table each document

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up your input by assuming each dictionary is held in a list as follows:

```
doc = [
{
    "uid": "111",
    "data": [{
        "eid": "111a",
        "ori": ""
    },
    {
        "eid": "111b",
        "ori": ""       
    }]
},
{
    "uid": "222",
    "data": [{
        "eid": "222a",
        "ori": ""
    }]
},
{
    "uid": "333",
    "data": [{
        "eid": "333a",
        "ori": ""
    }]
},
{
    "uid": "444",
    "data": [{
        "eid": "444a",
        "ori": ""
    },
    {
        "eid": "444b",
        "ori": ""       
    }]
}]


found = 0
for d in doc:
    data = d['data']
    for x in data:
        if 'ori' in x:
            found += 1
print(found)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how to query from mongodb server with pymongo ? i mean something like using .find, .aggregate or $group ?

Comment: That wasn't the question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Pymongo `$count(aggregation)` may [help](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/):

```py
docs = db.doc.aggregate( [
   { $group: { _id: null, myCount: { $sum: 1 } } },
   { $project: { _id: 0 } }
] )
```

The operation returns the following results:

```py
{
    "myCount": 4
}
```